# Any way to implement 'is'/'as' for dynamic or at least fake it?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

I have a type `ConfigValue` that exposes a dynamic interface via an implementation of `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` and custom `DynamicMetaObject` instance.

An instance of this type can be seen, of course, as it's native type - analogous to an XML Element - but it can also be seen as an instance of any other object type, according to the contents of the XML and what kind of object it builds (it's a proprietary IOC built by little old me).

So

```
<value>10</value>
```

Can be seen as a `ConfigValue` but also potentially a `string`, `short`, `double` etc.  Conversion is achieved by implicit or explicit cast, as specified by the calling language.  The XML gets more complicated because you can fire constructors, methods, property gets etc.

To achieve this, of course, I have overriden the `BindConvert` member of the `DynamicMetaObject` type - and if the conversion is unsupported by the `ConfigValue` object at runtime, then a runtime error occurs (which is fine).

I've just started writing a piece of code where it would be great if I could do a safe cast to the target type, but if that doesn't work fallback to some other logic - analogous to:

```
public DesiredType Foo(dynamic d)
{
  DesiredType dt = d as dt;
  if(dt != null)
    return dt;
  //TODO: Fallback logic to build dt from d
}
```

But, C# at least (and probably all dynamic-aware languages I'm sure) doesn't emit any dynamic binding for the 'as' or 'is' operations; presumably because `DynamicMetaObject` doesn't have a method for such a test.  Thus the type test is just performed on the static type information which, in this case, always fails.

As a result I'm having to rely on the rather ugly:

```
public DesiredType Foo(dynamic d)
 {
   try
   {
      return (DesiredType)d;
   }
   catch(Exception)
   {
     //TODO: fallback logic
   }
 }
```

Any ideas how I can avoid the try/catch/gulp pattern here!?  The best I can think of is something on top of `DynamicMetaObject`; but then that has to be queried for first, before then being queried again for the type test; which is just going to explode the code up even further!

Comment: I tried checking for `ExpressionType.TypeIs` in the `TryBinaryOperation` method on a `DynamicObject`. No luck - the C# compiler always emits the IL. I think the best thing to do would be to provide a `Is(Type)` and `Is<T>()` method. Although keep in mind that a cast still does the trick (`TryConvertTo`) so you could just use casts instead of `as`s.

Comment: @Jonathan - I've done it with a static method in the end rather than extending the dynamic object/provider.  I wonder if there's a case to see about getting this ability added to the DLR... probably not!

Comment: I really think you should open it on http://connect.microsoft.com - it is a shortcoming (considering the `ExpressionType` enumeration has the `TypeIs` value).

Comment: @Jonathan - you're right - I've got a 50/50 hit rate on there so far, so I might just do that!

Comment: Can you show how your override of BindConvert works?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible.

Take for example, this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic d = new object();

        var x = (Program)d;
        Console.WriteLine(x);

        var y = d as Program;
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        var z = d is Program;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

If we decompile it using Reflector we see that the only reason that the cast is able to be intercepted by the dynamic type is that the C# compiler does a lot of extra work in order to support it:

```
class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object d = new object();
        if (<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1 == null)
        {
            <Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1 = CallSite<Func<CallSite, object, Program>>.Create(Binder.Convert(CSharpBinderFlags.ConvertExplicit, typeof(Program), typeof(Program)));
        }
        Console.WriteLine(<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1.Target(<Main>o__SiteContainer0.<>p__Site1, d));

        Program y = d as Program;
        Console.WriteLine(y);

        bool z = d is Program;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

In contrast, the `as` and `is` calls are simply compiled down to IL instructions, with no added magic from the C# compiler.

This fits in with the normal casting operators as well; using `as` rather than a cast will not perform any conversion casts, so will never change the type of the underlying object.

Comment: Yeah - I've decompiled and noted that as/is don't get translated to dynamic operations; as I say in my question it's likely to be because `DynamicMetaObject` doesn't offer a dynamic binding for it

Answer (score 1):

`is` and `as` are ***runtime*** tests that ***only*** work on inheritance, thus they don't need to dynamically bind because they are already dynamic. Even without the dynamic keyword you could never use `is` or `as` to test for implict or explicit conversions, and they never would work on value types like `short` and `double` either.

So your answer is that there is no need to fake it, they work *exactly* the same for dynamic types as static types. Your `try` `catch` is probably the best way to test the conversion, catching binding errors is what the DLR is already doing in the background for a lot of it's fallback cases. You can see for yourself in the debugger if you stop on first chance exceptions.

The best way to improve your `try` `catch` would be to specify the exact exception.

```
 catch(RuntimeBinderException)
   {
     //TODO: fallback logic
   }
```

Comment: good point about the fact that they don't test for conversions - meaning that it would actually be nonsense to bind it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of the fact that it's not supported, I've written this very basic static method to simplify the operation of testing the conversion.

```
public static class DynamicHelper
{
    public static TResult As<TResult>(dynamic obj) where TResult : class
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return null;
        try
        {
            return (TResult)obj;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It's top-drawer code that ;)