# How to override DynamicMetaObject.BindConvert to accept Cast to Interface

Tags: c#, dynamic, proxy

Using the code below I'm trying to get the override correct for BindConverter to allow casting to the interface T

```
class DynamicProxy<T> : DynamicObject
{
    private T t;
    public DynamicProxy(T t)
    {
        this.t = t;
    }
    public override DynamicMetaObject GetMetaObject(Expression parameter)
    {
        return new DynamicProxyMetaObject(parameter, this);
    }
    class DynamicProxyMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject
    {
        public DynamicProxyMetaObject(Expression expression, DynamicObject value)
            : base(expression, BindingRestrictions.Empty, (object)value)
        {                
        }
        public override DynamicMetaObject BindConvert(ConvertBinder binder)
        {
            return base.BindConvert(binder);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I *suspect* you can't do this - based on the fact that custom conversions to interface types aren't permitted anyway. I could be wrong though - and the code generated when casting a dynamic value to an interface definitely *does* use the normal dynamic conversion route. What happens with the code you've tried?

Comment: This article seems to appear to allude it might be possible but I have to admit it goes much deeper into dynamic that I wanted.  I just wanted to use a simple DynamicObject. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ff800651.aspx

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I've never implemented a BindConvert override so I don't have any idea how one would go about customizing this.  The code above is as far as I got.

Comment: Ah, okay. I'd assumed you really *wanted* to use the meta object... there may be a simpler option.

Comment: As per [your comment on my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6924581/any-way-to-implement-is-as-for-dynamic-or-at-least-fake-it?noredirect=1#comment21736835_6924581) a moment ago @AaronStainback, I'll put together an example implementation for you.

Comment: @AaronStainback answer added. should do what you want I think.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a working implementation of BindConvert:

```
public override DynamicMetaObject BindConvert(ConvertBinder binder)
{
    BindingRestrictions restrictions 
        = BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType);
    //if the type requested is compatible with the 
    //instance, there's no conversion to be done.
    if (binder.Type.IsAssignableFrom(LimitType))
        return binder.FallbackConvert(
            new DynamicMetaObject(Expression, restrictions, Value));

    if (LimitType.IsGenericType && 
        LimitType.GetGenericTypeDefinition().Equals(typeof(DynamicProxy<>)))
    {
        //get the type parameter for T
        Type proxiedType = LimitType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        //now check that the proxied type is compatible 
        //with the desired conversion type
        if(binder.ReturnType.IsAssignableFrom(proxiedType))
        {
            //this FieldInfo lookup can be cached by 
            //proxiedType in a static ConcurrentDictionary
            //to cache the reflection for future use
            FieldInfo tField = LimitType.GetField("t", 
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            //return a field expression that retrieves the 
            //private 't' field of the DynamicProxy
            //note that we also have to convert 'Expression'
            //to the proxy type - which we've already ascertained
            //is the LimitType for this dynamic operation.
            var fieldExpr = Expression.Field(
                Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType), tField);
            //but because we're allowing bases or interfaces of 'T',
            //it's a good idea to chuck in a 'Convert'
            return new DynamicMetaObject(
                Expression.Convert(fieldExpr, binder.ReturnType),
                restrictions);
        }
    }

    return base.BindConvert(binder);
}
```

And here's a test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConvert()
{
    List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "Hello", "World" };
    //proxy a List<string>
    DynamicProxy<List<string>> proxy1 =
        new DynamicProxy<List<string>>(myList);

    dynamic proxyDynamic = proxy1;
    //dynamic 'cast' to List<string> (the actual 'T')
    //should return same instance, because the conversion
    //simply gets the private 't' field.
    List<string> fromDynamic1 = (List<string>)proxyDynamic;
    Assert.AreSame(myList, fromDynamic1);
    //dynamic 'cast' to a base or interface of T
    //In this case, IEnumerable<string>
    IEnumerable<string> fromDynamic2 = (IEnumerable<string>)proxyDynamic;
    Assert.AreSame(myList, fromDynamic2);
}
```

And a test for exactly what you've asked for - i.e. where `T` is an interface - also works just as well:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestConvert2()
{
  List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "Hello", "World" };
  DynamicProxy<IEnumerable<string>> proxy =
    new DynamicProxy<IEnumerable<string>>(myList);

  dynamic proxyDynamic = proxy;
  var fromDynamic = (IEnumerable<string>)proxyDynamic;
  Assert.AreSame(myList, fromDynamic);      
}
```

*As the tests show, you not only get a dynamic cast to `T`, but also to any base or interface of `T`.  However, note that the implementation first does a check to see if the target type is a base/interface of the `DynamicProxy<T>` - so a dynamic cast to `object` (although why you'd do that I don't know) will actually return the proxy instance.  You can disable that behaviour by getting rid of the first `if` statement after the first line of `BindConvert`.*

The use of `LimitType` in the `BindConvert` method is crucial, as it gives you the runtime type of the object hiding behind the dynamic expression.  The `Expression` property of the meta object will typically only have a type of `Object` - which is no good for fishing into the object and calling methods or reading properties/fields, which is what we need to do to support dynamic casting.

So, using `LimitType` enables us to peer inside actual `DynamicProxy<T>` instance, getting both it's `T` but also access to the instance field `t` (it's private, but the expression compiler can cope with that).  After confirming that the desired target type of the conversion is compatible with the `T` of the `DynamicProxy<T>`, we emit an expression that reads that field and returns the object as the result of the conversion.

Incidentally - in the second test we *can't* currently do a dynamic cast to `List<string>`, even though the proxied object we pass in is `List<string>` - because that would require a slight change to the initial type-checking logic, and then introspection on the instance stored in the field 't' to check that it's actual type is compatible with the requested conversion type.  I haven't done the implementation that way because I think it's much less likely that you'd want to do that.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comments they have helped my understanding of dynamic a lot but this is not quite what I'm looking for.  When I cast to type of (Interface) and then I make calls to that interface I'm wanting to still go through the proxy for those calls and not the underlying type.  I don't want the cast to return the private t.  I want the cast to return the actual DynamicObject.

Comment: Ah... You're going to need to do some IL emit stuff then to generate a class in memory at runtime - C# and .Net in general doesn't allow dynamic implementation of interfaces or bases for that matter (I believe there are one or two languages built on the runtime that do - but they do a lot of work at runtime).  I think you might be better off looking at Castle's DynamicProxy

Comment: I'm trying to find an alternative to Castle's DynamicProxy that is easy and somewhat efficient, easy being the big part.

Comment: Yeah I can understand - but unfortunately there's no way around runtime IL emit - and it's not trivial to do either.  I wrote a library that dynamic implemented bases/abstracts/interfaces (you could dynamically build implementations from other types and static methods, add cross-cutting, argument inspection and auto exception handling) and it was quite a bit of work!  It was also not *easy* to use either :( !